# Pass chosen Laravel dropdown option into the controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

View:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'agents/searchStaff', 
                    'class'=>'form-search', 
                    'role'=>'form')) }}

        <select class="form-control">
          @foreach ($company->users as $user)
          <option id="{{ $user->id }}" name="agent">
                      {{ $user->firstname }} {{ $user->surname }}
          </option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Route:

```
Route::post('agents/searchStaff', 'AgentsController@postSearchStaff');
```

Controller:

```
public function postSearchStaff()
{
    $agent_id = Input::get('agent');
    dd($agent_id); // For testing purposes - Always returns NULL.
}
```

I'm unsure as to why the option value's ID isn't being passed onto the controller. Any help and guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you not looking for value attribute instead of id attribute on the OPTION?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `id={{ $user->id }}` to `value={{ $user->id }}`,

but this:

```
<select class="form-control">
  @foreach ($company->users as $user)
    <option id="{{ $user->id }}" name="agent">
      {{ $user->firstname }} {{ $user->surname }}
    </option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

can be done in one line with a bit sugar in your model:

```
// view
{{ Form::select('agent', $users, $selectedAgentId, $attributes) }}

// User model
public function getFullnameAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['firstname'].' '.$this->attributes['surname'];
}

// controller:
$users = $company->users->lists('fullname','id'); // Collection method
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 <select class="form-control">
     @foreach ($company->users as $user)
         <option id="{{ $user->id }}" name="agent">
             {{ $user->firstname }} {{ $user->surname }}
         </option>
     @endforeach
 </select>
```

to

```
 <select class="form-control" name="agent">
     @foreach ($company->users as $user)
         <option value="{{ $user->id }}">
             {{ $user->firstname }} {{ $user->surname }}
         </option>
     @endforeach
 </select>
```